# WSO2 Carbon: get local entry remotely

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have Local Entry on WSO2 ESB 4.6.0.
Is it possible to fetch it remotely?
(I mean outside of Synapse; like it is possible to get Resources/Collection from Registry with RemoteRegistry).

P.S. I've tried with [LocalEntryAdmin](http://www.massapi.com/source/wso2esb-4.0.0-src/components/localentry/org.wso2.carbon.localentry/3.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/localentry/service/LocalEntryAdmin.java.html), but it fetches entries from synapseConfiguration.

---

I'm trying to get registry (to get then local entry) from standalone Java app with [WSRegistryServiceClient](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/WS-API+Sample).
I copied jks and axis2repo but still get:

```
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to perform get operation.    at  org.wso2.carbon.registry.ws.client.registry.WSRegistryServiceClient.get(WSRegistryServiceClient.java:247)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
```

Should I use WSRegistryServiceClient only from Carbon environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from Registry. Using registry API, get the Localregistry and try to read it as a resource;

```
localRegistry().get("testLocalentry");
```

Comment: Thanks Ratha. How would I get Local Registry outside Synapse? Because when I call remoteRegistry.get("testLocalentry") it throws "RegistryException: Method Not Allowed".

Comment: Check this; http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.1.1/docs/developer_guide/remote_api.html

Comment: @Ratha - when I click on that link, I am asked for my username and password.

Comment: Just cancel it..if not working try this..we moved to new doc structure..that is bit older one http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Basic+Registry+API+Knowledge

Comment: Is it possible to get local entry with WSRegistryServiceClient?